# google.cloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 and optimise google datastore put_multi() speed

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to insert 150k+ rows/`entities` into `datastore` using `Python` and `datastore emulator`.

```
    def add_rows(self, val_dicts):
        # val_dicts is a list of dictionaries for updating the entities

        with self.client.transaction():

            entities = [Entity(self.client.key(self.kind)) for i in range(len(val_dicts))]

            for entity, update_dict in zip(entities, val_dicts):
                entity.update(update_dict)

            self.client.put_multi(entities)
```

the problem is `put_multi()` is taking an extensive amount of time for inserting the `entities`. I am wondering how to speed up its efficiency in general in `datastore` for inserting `entities`.

UPDATE. After waiting for a long time for `put_multi()`
 to finish, an error has occurred,

```
self.client.put_multi(entities)
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py:293: in __exit__
self.commit()
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/transaction.py:220: in commit
super(Transaction, self).commit()
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py:265: in commit
self._commit()
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py:242: in _commit
self.project, self._commit_request, self._id)
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_http.py:627: in commit
response = self._datastore_api.commit(project, request)
../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_http.py:356: in commit
return self._stub.Commit(request_pb)
/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py:77: in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

@contextlib.contextmanager
def _grpc_catch_rendezvous():
    """Re-map gRPC exceptions that happen in context.

    .. _code.proto: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/\
                    master/google/rpc/code.proto

    Remaps gRPC exceptions to the classes defined in
    :mod:`~google.cloud.exceptions` (according to the description
    in `code.proto`_).
    """
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions.GrpcRendezvous as exc:
        error_code = exc.code()
        error_class = _GRPC_ERROR_MAPPING.get(error_code)
        if error_class is None:
            raise
        else:
>               raise error_class(exc.details())
E               google.cloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 {"created":"@1488386955.558948202","description":"Secure read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.c","file_line":157,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1488386955.558925887","description":"EOF","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":235}]}

../../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_http.py:260: ServiceUnavailable
```

How to resolve the issue here?

Comment: How many entities are you sending in a single PUT? Are you possibly hitting the limits? https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla I sent 150000 `entities` to `put_multi`.

Comment: Perhaps you should try sending them in batches of 500 or less and see if that resolves the issue (also check the other limits you might be hitting depending on the size of your entities).

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla any reference on the size limit of `put_multi`, batch is definitely worth trying, cheers